# Cast extended char to int java

Tags: java, string, char, int

I am working on an Android app that receives data in String format through BLE.
This string contains ADC values in HEX format. To save storage space, I contained two hex values per byte (for example `0xED`). However, I can't retrieve these values from the string. 
So I need to be able to get an `int[]` from the string splitting every indexed char in two.

As for now I tried to get `charAt(index)`, and then casting `char` to `int`. However, this only works for ASCII valid data. Once the data goes above 127 for one char, it returns a default value for exceptions. Is there any way to avoid this?

The code below works fine for every value below 127, so i just need a solution for the values above 127.

```html
for (int i = 0; i < 119; i++) {
            char charTemp1 = datastring.charAt(i);
            int test = charTemp1 & 0xF0;
            int test2 = charTemp1 & 0xF;
            }
```

Comment: [Parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) them with a radix of 16

Comment: Please put up a [mcve]. Show us example code that creates such a string, and where you stuck.

Comment: Do not abuse Strings to store arbitrary bytes. That may have worked in C, but not here.

Comment: That's probably the problem, i'm starting mainly from a C background. So, any suggestions? The String is what is delivered by the BLE example on Android, so I suppose I have to start from the String..

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller what is the way to go in Java then? :)

Comment: @Barrybas: use a byte array instead

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explain more about how your input string format works.  You show 119 characters for a string that supposedly contains pairs of hex digits, and I don't understand that.  Note below that I give an example in the code as `testVector`.  How does your string differ?

```
public class ParseInt
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String testVector = "EDAB1234";
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( parseInts(testVector) ) );
   }

   public static int[] parseInts( String hex ) {
      int[] retVal = new int[ hex.length() / 2 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < hex.length()/2; i++ ) {
         retVal[i] = Integer.parseInt( hex.substring( i*2, i*2+2), 16 );
      }
      return retVal;
   }

}
```

Comment: My string looks like "!Ce����" or 0x21 43 65 87 A9 CB ED 0F. So there are 2 hex values per character in the String

Comment: And what do you want the output to be?  Those aren't hex digits.

Comment: i would like to separate the single hex values

Comment: I think you should update your question with the additional information.  Please provide examples for everything.  Right now your comments make no sense.  I don't understand what "separate" means in this context or what a "hex value" is.

Comment: Sorry for being a little cloudy :) So what i would like to achieve is an int[] which contains (for my example string) [2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,14,13,0,15]